# connecting onDndDrop with dojo.dnd.Source

Tags: events, dojo

can any one tell me how to connect a dojo/dnd/Source object with onDndDrop event and its function

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This tutorial contains everything you need to get started with dojo.dnd:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/10/dojo-drag-and-drop-1/

Answer (score 0):

In case the link ever goes away or someone wants to use AMD, to connect the **onDndDrop** event to a `dojo/dnd/Source`, you can write the following:

```js
require(["dojo/dnd/Source", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Source) {
    var myDndSource = new Source("myDndSource");
    myDndSource.on("DndDrop", function(source, nodes, copy, target) {
        // Do something
    });
});
```

For example:

```js
require(["dojo/dnd/Source", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Source) {
    var myDndSource = new Source("myDndSource");
    myDndSource.on("DndDrop", function(source, nodes, copy, target) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
           console.log("Dropped '" + node.innerText + "' on source '" + source.node.id + "'");
        });
        console.log("New order: " + source.getAllNodes().map(function(node) {
           return node.innerText;
        }).join(", "));
    });
});
```

A full code example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/RFav3/